# Problem of the urn and hypergeometric distribtuion

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A box contains n balls, b are white, we draw without a replacement r ball, whats the probability that the r balls are all white?
Proof : this problem follows the hypergeometric distribution (idk why i just googled it and it was on wikipedia), thus $P(X=r) = \frac{C^r _b C^{n-b}_{r-r}}{C^r_n} $ is this valid?
also what i dont understand in the hypergeometric distribution is why we multiply by the number of way of getting the non white balls like whats the idea behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Classically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_definition_of_probability), probability is the number of successful outcomes, divided by the number of total outcomes.

For your problem, both of these numbers are [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

In particular, the total number of ways to choose $r$ of the $n$ balls is $\binom{n}{r}$. Likewise, the number of ways to choose $r$ of the $b$ white balls is $\binom{b}{r}$.

Therefore, the desired probability is $$\displaystyle\frac{\#\text{ of successful outcomes}}{\#\text{ of total outcomes}}\, = \, \displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\binom{b}{r}}{\displaystyle\binom{n}{r}}$$

Comment: yes but in the hypergeometric distribution we have an extra term in the numerator why is that?

Comment: The [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is about $k$ successes in $n$ draws, whereas you are asking here about the specific case where $k=n$ (you want $k$ successes in $k$ draws). In the case $k=n$, the extra term in the numerator is equal to $1$.

Comment: but assume k is different from n, why does the extra term arise?

Comment: Think about the case $k = 3$, $K = 5$, $n = 4$, $N = 8$. This is the following problem: "There are $8$ total balls of which $5$ are white. You draw $4$ balls without replacement. What is the probability that you draw exactly $3$ white balls?" If you count carefully and solve this specific example, you will likely understand where the extra term in the formula comes from.

Comment: infinite thanks i now see the logic behind it